# How to iterate through textboxes and apply calculations

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application with 20 `textboxes`, which they do get their values from a `database` when a selection is made in a `combobox`. I need to do the calculations (sum the `textBoxes`  values) and display the result on `label` or in a `textbox` when the `combobox` selection is choosen.

I added the `texBoxes` into an `array` and then iterate through them. But I’m getting 0 as the result.

**The Problem**:

[image]

**My Code:**

```
private void sumTextBoxes()
    {
        TextBox[] txt;
        txt = new TextBox[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, textBox6, textBox7, textBox8, textBox9, textBox10 };

        int value;

        foreach (TextBox tb in txt)
        {
            if(tb !=null)
            {
                if (int.TryParse(tb.Text, out value))
                {
                    if (textBox11.Text.Length > 0)
                    {
                        textBox11.Text = (int.Parse(textBox11.Text) + value).ToString();
                    }
                    else
                        textBox11.Text = value.ToString();
                }
            }


            //label3.Text = Convert.ToString(value);

        }
        }
```

Where am I wrong? or a better way to solve it?
PS: The textboxes on the left 1-10 and the total is 11 and on the right 12-21 total is 22

Comment: What is the problem? It is not clear from the image(at least for me)

Comment: You'd probably better seperate your UI and data -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584831/separation-of-logic-and-ui and than do the sum at the data level

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following solution works with doubles, refreshes the sum textbox only once and reduces the parsing work to minimum :

```
private void sumTextBoxes()
{
    TextBox[] txt;
    txt = new TextBox[] { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5, textBox6, textBox7, textBox8, textBox9, textBox10 };

    double sum = 0;
    double value;

    foreach (TextBox tb in txt)
    {
        if (tb !=null)
        {
            if (double.TryParse(tb.Text, out value))
            {
                sum += value;
            }
        }
    }

    textBox11.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

Comment: It works with doubles (and it seems useful from printscreen), refreshes textBox11 only once, reduces parsing work.

Comment: I mean: Please explain in your answer what you are doing rather than dumping some code.

Comment: @Bioukh. It works perfectly but an explaination will be cool for the others too. Thnx

Comment: Can u please explain exactly what this line does? `if (double.TryParse(tb.Text, out value))`

Comment: `double.TryParse()` does the same than `int.TryParse()` but for doubles instead of integers. In your printscreen, there is one double (819752,52) so it seems to be more appropriate to use `double.TryParse()`.

Answer (score 1):

To sum up all the data you can use *Linq*:

```
  textBox11.Text = txt
    .Where(item => item != null) // <- Actually you don't need this
    .Select(item => { // form TextBox to its integer value and parse result
      int value;
      Boolean result = int.TryParse(item.Text, out value);
      return new {
        result = result,
        value = value
      };
    })
    .Where(item => item.result) // filter out all that parsed
    .Sum(item => item.value)
    .ToString();
```

Think on not *explicitly putting* `TextBox`es into array but *query* them as well:

```
textBox11.Text = Controls // <- if the TextBoxes are on the form
  .Cast<TextBox>()
  .Where(item => item != textBox11) // <- all TextBoxes except that with a total
  .Select(item => {
...
```

Comment: Some explanation might be useful. There is a lot of code in your post that fresh programmers don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a key part of the documentation for [Int32.Tryparse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When this method returns, contains the 32-bit signed integer value equivalent of the number contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, or zero if the conversion failed. The conversion fails if the s parameter is null or String.Empty, is not of the correct format, or represents a number less than MinValue or greater than MaxValue. **This parameter is passed uninitialized; any value originally supplied in result will be overwritten.**

This means you cannot apply sum operations as you might normally (return an int, add to previous result, repeat).

So how, to fix that? A temporary variable and summing the result if the return value of `TryParse()` is true is one way:

```
// A mock but the idea is the same            
var tx = new[] { new TextBox { Text = "1" }, new TextBox { Text = "2" }, new TextBox { Text = "" }, new TextBox { Text = "3" } };

var sum = 0;
foreach (TextBox t in tx) {
    var temp = 0;
    if (Int32.TryParse(t.Text, out temp)) {
        sum += temp; 
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

I imagine you may also be able to come up with a LINQ-ish way of doing this, but that would likely end up being more confusing that anything else. For a task like this I'd stick which readability.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see - you're using string field `textBox11.Text` to store integer data, and converting it to string and back to integer.

If you don't have **very** strong reason of doing so (probably left out of question scope) - it's better to sum all the integer values into integer variable, not string one.

```
int value;
int result = 0;

foreach (TextBox tb in txt)
{
    if(tb !=null)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(tb.Text, out value))
        {
            result += value;
        }
    }
}

label3.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be using a `DataGridView` instead of these many textboxes. Take a look at following working sample (for very simple computing).

```
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    private void CalculatedFieldGrid_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        table.Columns.Add("Name");
        table.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));

        table.Rows.Add();
        table.Rows[0][0] = "One";
        table.Rows[0][1] = 10;

        table.Rows.Add();
        table.Rows[1][0] = "Two";
        table.Rows[1][1] = 20;

        table.Rows.Add();
        table.Rows[2][0] = "Three";
        table.Rows[2][1] = 30;

        table.Rows.Add();
        table.Rows[3][0] = "Four";
        table.Rows[3][1] = 40;

        table.Rows.Add();
        table.Rows[4][0] = "Calculated Value: ";

        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

        comboBox1.Items.Add("Add");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Average");
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            table.Rows[4][1] = table.Compute("Sum(Count)", null);
        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            table.Rows[4][1] = table.Compute("Avg(Count)", null);
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }
```